# Can freelancers publish code in GitHub and claim it to be theirs?

Tags: united-states, copyright, licensing

I am curious to know the legal process of a collaborated effort for a code at a small startup.

Say I am the technical head of a startup, and I have about 90% of the code/commits. The other 10% is by temporary employees, interns, freelancers, etc. For the sake of this story, I will call one freelancer Alan.

For a particular project, Alan was given read access to a private repository, and write access to his branch.

What prevents Alan from copying our private code and pasting it on GitHub as his own 'published work', essentially granting him copyright over our work?

We could show git logs as proof that we had access to the code before he arrived, but git logs are easy to modify, and histories can be rewritten.

On GitHub, say Alan uses his signed keys, removes the entire git history and makes a commit with the final state of our whole codebase as his 'Initial Commit'.

What legal standing do we have (or proof) if we have not made Alan sign any documents specifically saying he is not allowed to publish our code anywhere (but we also haven't signed any document saying he IS allowed to publish our code).

Updates: 
There has been some discussion, so I would like to ask a more concrete question. **Is it proof enough that Alan posted the code at a given time first(which was verified through something like Github's signature on the commit) that I cannot file for a copyright?**(since he has published his code and gotten it verified, but we did not used 3rd party signed commits)

Comment: I think you're confusing two questions: whether you own copyright in your code (yes, you do), and whether you can prove it (you probably can, but that needs more information).

Comment: How is this different from Alan taking $1000 from the safe and claiming it's his?

Comment: This very much calls for a lawyer and a lawsuit. We have opinions, but you need a court order.

Comment: Note that the answer may be dependent on jurisdiction. Please add a country tag. Notably, US law can be quite different from that of other countries.

Answer (score 38):

Provided you are in one of the 170+ countries signatory to the Berne Convention (the current 10 non-signatories are, exhaustively: Eritrea, Marshall Islands, Nauru, Palau, San Marino, Iran, Iraq, Ethiopia, Somalia, and South Sudan), then copyright comes into existence at the moment a work is fixed in a tangible medium, not when it is published. The initial copyright owner is the author of the work. In cases of employment, the "author" might be the natural person who authored the work, or the corporate person who employed the natural author.

To clarify your thinking about registration: copyright registration is a public record of authorship (or copyright ownership). Registration does not create a copyright, but is merely a recording of the copyright that was automatically created at the moment of original authorship.

Depending on circumstances and jurisdiction, Alan might have a legitimate claim to copyright on his own work. However, he will be quite hard-pressed to find a convincing theory of law that allows him to publish the unpublished copyrighted work of *other people* without their permission.

This leaves him either to admit defeat -- he cannot possibly own the copyright of his coworkers' code, so he cannot have legally reproduced it -- or else make the baldfaced lie that the code has no other authors other than Alan himself. For your company to disprove such a claim, you may employ sworn testimony of your coworkers, you may employ code analysis to show differing coding styles (suggestive of multiple authors), or you may show code backups or version control history showing the progressive authorship of the work over time by many people. (Sure, a Git history is possible to fake, but a realistic history with feature branches, "whoops, undid the typo in the last commit" messages, etc. would lend significant weight to your company being the original authors.)

Comment: Please qualify your statement with the relevant jurisdiction (country), as rules such as "Copyright comes into existence at the moment a work is fixed in a tangible medium, not when it is published" are not universally true.

Comment: @jcaron Fair point; done.

Answer (score 18):

This is a fairly complex question and it depends heavily on what jurisdictions are involved. In the US software development by regular employees will typically be classified as "work for hire" and the copyright will belong to the employer. For contractors the situation is more complex and you haven't done yourself any favors by not having written agreements with your contributors. Depending on the exact circumstances and jurisdiction, Alan may actually have a legitimate claim to the copyright of the code he wrote, though not to the code he didn't write.

To be quite literal, there is nothing that prevents Alan from taking the code, putting it on GitHub and claiming copyright. However it is only a claim. You are free to take Alan to court and assert your own ownership of the copyright. Your case is weaker because Alan is apparently a contractor rather than a regular employee and you have no written agreement. However you can still claim that Alan didn't write much of the code, and that the parts he did write were [a contribution to a collective work](https://www.henryparklaw.com/post/2017/10/05/computer-software-as-a-work-made-for-hire).

It would then be up to you and Alan to bring the best evidence for both your cases before the court, and the court would decide on the preponderance of the evidence. Yes, log files can be altered, but log files *in conjunction with sworn testimony* from your other contributors would still cary weight.

Comment: From whatever, I am understanding about this situation(after being migrated 2 times already), it is vague and often difficult to assert first publication (what if I apply for a copyright in the US copyright office?), and the specifics of the situation are much more important and entirely upto the discretion of the judge

Comment: @harveyslash "Alan may actually have a legitimate claim to the copyright of the code he wrote, though not to the code he didn't write." To put this another way, Alan absolutely has no right to publish the work done by other people; he might or might not (depending on jurisdiction) have a right to publish the code he wrote. All the subsequent evidentiary questions boil down to, "Could Alan persuade a judge/jury of the lie that he wrote all the code himself?" If he can turn that lie into courtroom reality, then the law applies itself to the situation as the court has (mis) understood it.

Comment: Unless Alan goes and studies the entire codebase carefully, you should simply be able to challenge his claim by asking him under oath to describe the details of the portions he didn't write, and then let his lawyers challenge the real authors on those sections on the witness stand.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan those "real authors" have had plenty of time to study "their" code while faking the entire history.

Answer (score 5):

The details will vary based on your locale, but I'm answering this assuming your locale is a party to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) (since most are).

> What prevents Alan from copying our private code and pasting it on
>   GitHub as his own 'published work', essentially granting him copyright
>   over our work?

This would not grant him copyright in any way.  Publishing something does not give you any rights that you didn't have before you published.

> What legal standing do we have (or proof) if we have not made Alan
>   sign any documents specifically saying he is not allowed to publish
>   our code anywhere (but we also haven't signed any document saying he
>   IS allowed to publish our code).

As the author of the code, you hold the copyright and all rights to the code are yours alone.  You don't technically have to get Alan to sign something saying he isn't allowed to copy the code.  The default position is that the only person allowed to copy, modify, use, distribute, etc. a copyrighted work is the copyright owner.  The purpose of a *software license* is to give someone else limited permissions to use the copyrighted code.  If Alan can't produce a valid license showing that you gave him permission to do what he did, then what he did isn't legal.

> Is it proof enough that Alan posted the code at a given time
>   first(which was verified through something like Github's signature on
>   the commit) that I cannot file for a copyright?(since he has published
>   his code and gotten it verified, but we did not used 3rd party signed
>   commits)

Publishing or posting something is irrelevant to copyright ownership.  The author of a work automatically owns the copyright as soon as that work is "fixed" in a medium (meaning, as soon as it's printed on paper, saved to a file, recorded, etc).  You don't have to publish it or register anything, it's completely automatic.  If I hack Steven King's laptop, steal an unreleased manuscript, and publish it, Mr. King still owns all of the copyright.  I can't take ownership of the copyright unless the copyright owner *voluntarily* transfers it to me.

Also, a signed Github commit verifies that the commit hasn't been tampered with and that the committer's identity hasn't been spoofed.  This is useful from a software security standpoint, but is completely irrelevant as far as copyright goes.  A "verified" commit doesn't indicate anything about whether the committer had the legal right to use the associated code.  This is good for you, because now it's a whole lot harder for Alan to defend himself by arguing that someone else committed the code and made it look like he did it.  The act of distributing the stolen material is stamped with his verified identity, which makes your lawyers' jobs easier.

I have a feeling you might be confusing copyright and patents in a lot of this.  Copyrights are automatic and publication and registration are optional and irrelevant.  Patents, however, must be filed and awarded, and many locales have a "first to file" rule.  It is possible for someone to steal a design and patent it before the rightful owner can do so.  Such a patent (if it was granted) would be completely invalid, however, and you could get it overturned in court or by an appeals process (plus sue for damages).  Software generally isn't patented - and in some locales *cannot* be patented - so this likely won't apply to your work.

Backdating commits won't really help Alan.  As you mentioned, commit logs can be forged, so they're unlikely to be given much legal weight.  Github's server logs know when the repository was created and when the code was pushed to the repo, and this information would be much more trustworthy in a legal case since it comes from a disinterested third party.  You also have the sworn testimony of everyone else who worked on the code base, plus indirect evidence like email threads discussing the code, reports showing screenshots of test builds, etc. that can't be faked as easy as a commit log.

Comment: "As the author of the code, you hold the copyright and all rights to the code are yours alone": this is not correct.  The company owns the copyright because it is a work made for hire.

Comment: @phoog> *“The company owns the copyright because it is a work made for hire”* → don't know how it works where you are, but where I live (France) this is wrong. The job contract must explicitly specify that the employee grants full copyright to their employer, it's not a given. (Software is an explicit exception to that rule so your statement would be right for software, but wrong in general here).

Comment: @phoog - I intended that sentence to refer to the code OP wrote before Alan was hired.  Meaning, Alan has zero copyright ownership in existing code unless OP expressly granted it to him.

Comment: @spectras I'm in the United States, and the question is tagged [tag:united-states], so while your comment is interesting for readers who might be employed under French law, it is not correct under US law.  A work created by an employee is automatically a "work made for hire."

Comment: @bta OP cannot grant copyright in the code that OP wrote before Alan was hired because OP does not control the copyright.  The company controls it.  Therefore the correct statement is "Alan has zero copyright ownership in existing code unless the company expressly granted it to him"

Comment: @phoog- Since he said he was the technical head of the company and wrote 90% of the code, I was treating OP as an officer capable of acting on behalf of the company.  All details will obviously differ due to local laws and individual contract details, but in this sort of hypothetical situation the concepts still hold.

Comment: @phoog> I do not know the various juridictions in the US and how they combine with federal laws, I was commenting so the assumption can be questioned if it needs to be. Possible catch if yes, no harm if not :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to have evidence of original authorship of a work *without originally disclosing the work* is to first put the work in its entirety along with an authorship file into a compressed archive and securely (e.g. SHA-2 or SHA-3) hash the archive. Then, the hash must be published in several reputable sources which will serve as a timestamp reference. This will provide strong evidence that the work was originally authored by your entity. However, the claim must still hold up against the theory that your entity had copied it from someone else who failed to cryptographically prove their possession of the work from a particular time.

The concept is similar to publishing Git's internal object hashes with authorship information included in each source file. However, Git traditionally uses SHA-1 for its internal hashing which has been shown to be insecure—it is transitioning to SHA-2 but this could take years [[1]](https://thenewstack.io/git-transitioning-away-from-the-aging-sha-1-hash/). A hash algorithm is insecure if collisions may be easily found. Assuming there is some arbitrary data sections in your files, a [collision attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) can make your work appear to have been in your possession at the time of your arbitrary previously published hash.

Comment: ah, you have an interesting point. Even though git logs and authors can be faked, the actual git changes will most likely be impossible to fake (I am assuming git computes a hash on the changes). Interesting. I never thought about those hashes

Comment: I believe that Git computes a hash only on each new version of a source file. Git's hashes themselves would be fine for this purpose if they used SHA-2 or SHA-3. Git is planning to migrate to SHA-2. But these hashes can be calculated at any time so it is still critical to have published them to trusted sources so they serve as witness to the time that you published them.